# "Spaghetti"-solutions for ODE nonautonomous system and reduced vector field

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, graphics3d, dynamic, nonlinear

[Projections of the 3-dimensional phase-space of a non-autonomous ODE system](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/247146/projections-of-the-3-dimensional-phase-space-of-a-non-autonomous-ode-system)

[Multidimensional obstacle avoidance in ODE (Visualization)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/246413/multidimensional-obstacle-avoidance-in-ode-visualization)

Given simple system of ODE:

$\begin{cases} \dot{x}=g \\ \dot{o}=2 \cdot(-o+x) \\ \dot{g}=(1+\sin(3 t)) \cdot (-g+\frac{df}{do}) \\ \dot{h}=-h+\frac{d^2f}{d^2o} \end{cases}$

where $f = e^{-o^2}$

It is not difficult to construct a 3D trajectory using the command `ParametricPlot3D`.

```
Clear["Derivative"]

ClearAll["Global`*"]

pars = {xs = -1, k = (1 + 1 Sin[3 t])};

f = Exp[-(o[t])^2];

s = NDSolve[{x'[t] == g[t], o'[t] == 2 (-o[t] + x[t]), 
    g'[t] == k (-g[t] + D[f, {o[t], 1}]), 
    h'[t] == -h[t] + D[f, {o[t], 2}], x[0] == xs, o[0] == xs, 
    g[0] == 0.01, h[0] == 0}, {x, o, g, h}, {t, 0, 200}, 
   MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]];
   
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{o[t], g[t], h[t]} /. s], {t, 0, 200}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, ColorFunction -> (Hue[#4] &), 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

**Questions:**

1. How to combine multiple solutions for different initial conditions on one `ParametricPlot3D`?
2. How to plot the final point on the `ParametricPlot3D`?
3. How to build a vector field around the trajectory?

Comment: I suggest using `ParametricNDSolveValue`.

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ I have not used this command before. Could you demonstrate this and frame it as an answer?

Comment: OK, please see my post below.

Comment: Perhaps a caveat: I've thought about this problem, off and on, for several years — albeit not very seriously. But that means that probably many people have thought about this problem, some seriously, at least since good, fast, color graphics have been available. AFAICT, no one has thought of a good solution. Even 3D phase spaces, which are possible to visualize, are rarely done; that might change with the new `StreamPlot3D`. As the dimension increases, the projection down to 3D graphics (on a 2D display) loses more and more information.  The system in the Q is 5D.

Comment: @MichaelE2 At the moment, I decided to give up the idea of visualizing a vector field, but for now I will work with trajectories. It's enough. And yes, the task is much more difficult than I thought.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several plots and the endpoints can be drawn by:

```
Clear["Derivative"]
ClearAll["Global`*"]
pars = {xs = -1, k = (1 + 1 Sin[3 t])};
f = Exp[-(o[t])^2];
s = Table[
   NDSolve[{x'[t] == g[t], o'[t] == 2 (-o[t] + x[t]), 
     g'[t] == k (-g[t] + D[f, {o[t], 1}]), 
     h'[t] == -h[t] + D[f, {o[t], 2}], x[0] == xs, o[0] == xs, 
     g[0] == g0, h[0] == 0}, {x, o, g, h}, {t, 0, 200}, 
    MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]], {g0, 0, 4, 0.8}];
funs[t_] = {o[t], g[t], h[t]} /. (Transpose[s][[1]]);
end = funs[200];

Show[{
  ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[funs[t]], {t, 0, 200}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
   ColorFunction -> (Hue[#4] &), BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
   PlotRange -> Full],
  Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.03], Point[end]}]
  }]
```

[image]

If you want different colors for different trajectories you simply eliminate the ColorFunction command:

```
Show[{ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[funs[t]], {t, 0, 200}, 
   PlotPoints -> 100, 
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotRange -> Full], 
  Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.03], Point[end]}]}]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

The velocity field is actually 4 dimensional and can not simply be drawn. What we can do is to draw velocity vectors along the trajectories:

```
velocities = 
  Table[Arrow[{{o[t], g[t], 
        h[t]}, {o[t], g[t], h[t]} + 0.5 {2 (-o[t] + x[t]), 
         k (-g[t] + D[f, {o[t], 1}]), -h[t] + D[f, {o[t], 2}]}}], {t, 
      0, 200}] /. (Transpose[s][[1]]) // Flatten;
Show[{
  ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[funs[t]], {t, 0, 200}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
   ColorFunction -> (Hue[#4] &), BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
   PlotRange -> Full],
  Graphics3D[{Thickness[Tiny], Arrowheads[0.02], velocities, 
    PointSize[0.03], Point[end]}]
  }]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Thanks for answer! Yes, this is exactly the problem, and this caused difficulties for me too. Do I understand correctly that a vector field cannot be extended to the entire specified range? (ie so that the entire "cube" is filled with vectors).

Comment: Don't you know how to assign a separate color to each curve?

Comment: And another question, how to build the same graphs if several initial conditions are set not for one variable, but for several variables? For example: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/175253/cant-get-parametric-ndsolve-to-work-for-three-ode-system

Comment: The velocity field changes with the time. Therefore, you would have to draw a vector field as a function of time, e.g. using `Manipulate`. I added how you could draw different colors for different trajectories.

Comment: Let's try to look at a vector field with `Manipulate`.

Answer (score 2):

The "final point" follows from

```
ode = {x'[t] == g[t], o'[t] == 2 (-o[t] + x[t]),g'[t] == k (-g[t] + D[f, {o[t], 1}]),h'[t] == -h[t] + D[f, {o[t], 2}]}
Reduce[ode/.   s_'[t] -> 0]
(*(g[t] == 0 && Sin[3 t] == -1 && h[t] == 2 E^-x[t]^2 (-1 + 2x[t]^2) &&o[t] == x[t]) || (x[t] == 0 && o[t] == 0 && h[t] == -2 && g[t] == 0)*)
```

FixedPoint: `x[t]==0,o[t]==0,g[t]==0,h[t]==-2`

Comment: Yes, it's just solving a system of equations. The problem is how to beautifully place this point on Plots?

Comment: Perhaps `Show[{"your plot", Graphics3D[{Red,Point[{0,0,-2}]]}]`

Comment: Is it possible to do this automatically, without manually entering the fixed point?

Comment: Calculate the  `fixpoint = {o[t], g[t], h[t]} /. 
  Solve[ode /. s_'[t] -> 0, {x[t], o[t], g[t], h[t]}][[1]] (*{0, 0, -2}*)` and use it  `Show[...,Point[fixpoint]...`

Answer (score 2):

With respect to 1., I suggest using [`ParametricNDSolveValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue.html)

```
Clear["Derivative"]
Clear[f, k, s]
f = Exp[-(o[t])^2];
k = (1 + 1 Sin[3 t]);
s = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x'[t] == g[t], o'[t] == 2 (-o[t] + x[t]), 
   g'[t] == k (-g[t] + D[f, {o[t], 1}]), 
   h'[t] == -h[t] + D[f, {o[t], 2}], x[0] == xs, o[0] == xs, 
   g[0] == 0.01, h[0] == 0}, {o[t], g[t], h[t]}, {t, 0, 200}, {xs}, 
   MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]
  ]
ParametricPlot3D[s /@ {-1, -1.5, -2} // Evaluate, {t, 0, 200}, PlotPoints -> 100, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

Comment: Thank you very much.